# VBA intellisense not working for Range.Columns.Find

Tags: excel, vba, methods, range, intellisense

I have defined a worksheet object called `SSIDWS` and when I get the `SSIDWS.Columns(3)` property and try to access additional methods afterwards like this: `SSIDWS.Columns(3).`, I am not getting the intellisense drop down to access methods for ranges, which is annoying because `.Columns(3)` returns a range, and even if I just type `SSIDWS.Columns(3).Find(` manually, I also don't get the helpful little box below that tells you what the arguments are. This is annoying, does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: I have a hunch why (note that `Cells` has similar behavior), but you could just use `.Range("C:C")` as well if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense usually does not work/offer suggestions for such collections. `ActiveWorkbook.sheets(1)` does not offer an intellisense option.

Being a range, you can use the next workaround:

```
Dim SSIDWS As Worksheet, C As Range
Set SSIDWS = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you want
   Set C = SSIDWS.Columns(3)
   'then intellisense will show up for C range...
```